# Simple Coordinate Puzzle with extra secret word

Tags: cipher, word-search

```
PETARM
TUDTOH
EOZRAT
NYFZHY
NEKILP
KSSONE
```

```
23SW242N355W436SW436S432SE211SE6
¡∞„¢£§Í„¢¡¡Í´§¢£˜´¢§¢´£™¡Í´™™¡Í£
```

> The decrypted answer should consist of two sentences with 7 words each, and then a single (secret) word.

Partial answers are welcome.

Hint:

> K = 

Comment: Maybe you can post a partial answer first?

Comment: Sure I will no problems

Comment: Wonderful puzzle.  Just remember, the people on this site are worldwide.  No need to be hasty with hints.   I just recently woke up, the puzzle was posted 2 hours ago and there is already a hint.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The word search:

> There are several words to be found here, including `THIS`, `TYPE`, and the `PUZZLE` across the diagonal which jumps out at you.

The line of letters and numbers:

> The beginning of this line has two digits followed by a letter; the end of the line has a single digit following a letter; and the remainder of the line shows digits in groups of three separated by one or two letters. The letters suggest points on a compass. Parse the line into groups like so:
>
> ```
> 23SW2 42N3 55W4 36SW4 36S4 32SE2 11SE6
> ```

> Note the last group `11SE6` seems to correspond to the word `PUZZLE` from the word search. The word begins at the top left of the grid, which has coordinates *(1, 1)*. It is read downward and to the right, in a *south east* direction. It is also *six* letters long. Decode the remaining groups into words using the same system:
>
> ```
> 23SW2 42N3 55W4 36SW4 36S4 32SE2 11SE6
> DO    YOU  LIKE THIS  TYPE OF    PUZZLE?
> ```

> I reply, `42S3`

The line of symbols:

> There are doubled symbols `¡¡` and `™™` in the same places as the line above has doubled digits `55` and `11`. This is enough to suggest that this line is the same type of code as the one above, but with a simple substitution applied to replace the letters and digits with symbols. Because the code groups always follow a pattern of digits and letters, either `11AA1` or `11A1`, we can approach this deductively.

> The first step is to distinguish the digits from the letters and delimit the line into code groups. The first two symbols must be digits, the last symbol must be a digit, and the third symbol and second-to-last symbols must be letters. Assign digits and letters to them arbitrarily.
>
> ```
> ¡∞„¢£§Í„¢¡¡Í´§¢£˜´¢§¢´£™¡Í´™™¡Í£
> 12N 3 E  11E   3      3 1E   1E3
> ```

> Because digits within the line must occur in groups of three, the `™` must be a digit. For the same reason, the `¢£§` near the beginning must be a run of three digits.
>
> ```
> ¡∞„¢£§Í„¢¡¡Í´§¢£˜´¢§¢´£™¡Í´™™¡Í£
> 12N435E 411E 543  454 361E 661E3
> ```

> We have assigned six digits, so the remainder must be letters. A two-letter group must begin with N or S. Thus, `Í˜` are from NS and `´„` are from EW.
>
> ```
> ¡∞„¢£§Í„¢¡¡Í´§¢£˜´¢§¢´£™¡Í´™™¡Í£
> 12W435NW411NE543SE454E361NE661N3
> ```

> These letters and digits are still placeholders, so it is time to solve another substitution. Break the line into groups and assume one of the groups must be the word `PUZZLE`. The only group that fits is `11NE5`. By coincidence, our digit 1 and letter E are correct. This gives us all of the letters (since there were only two options for each letter), and two of the digits.
>
> ```
> 12W4 35NW4 11NE5  43SE4 54E3 61NE6 61N3
> 1 W   6SW  11SE6    NE  6 E   1SE   1S
>            PUZZLE
> ```

> A word reading southwest in the grid which fits before `PUZZLE` is `THIS`, encoded as `36SW4`. This gives us two more words for free.
>
> ```
> 12W4 35NW4 11NE5  43SE4 54E3 61NE6 61N3
> 1 W4 36SW4 11SE6  43NE4 64E3  1SE   1S3
>      THIS  PUZZLE FROM  ONE
> ```

> Only the digits `25` remain, and finding a four letter word in the first row of the grid, reading to the west gives `RATE`.
>
> ```
> 12W4 35NW4 11NE5  43SE4 54E3 61NE6 61N3
> 15W4 36SW4 11SE6  43NE4 64E3 21SE2 21S3
> RATE THIS  PUZZLE FROM  ONE  TO    TEN
> ```

> To find the single, secret word, simply remove from the grid all letters which were used to decode the above:
>
> ```
> ......
> ...T.H
> ....A.
> ......
> N.....
> KS....
> ```

Thanks for the puzzle! I give it a 10/10.

Comment: There is a much more elegant way to solve the second sentence: rot13(uggcf://jjj.qpbqr.se/znp-bcgvba-xrl-pvcure), which follows from the hint.

Comment: I didn't see any hint until after I was done solving it. Also, we'll have to disagree on what "elegant" means.

Comment: We'll have to disagree on what "elegant" means: why?

Comment: Ah I see I knew it was a cipher but I couldn’t find the decoder in time

Comment: @NumberBasher "Guess the encoding" is not elegant.  Breaking the encoding using logical reasoning and instincts is elegant.  Bravo codewarrior0!

Comment: Ngl the fact that he cracked the code without using any website is seriously impressive

Comment: @PDT wins the Theodore Kaczynski award for no-computers...